# Is there a direct URL to subscribe to an ICS url on Windows Live calendar?

Tags: calendar, icalendar, windows-live

I'm looking for an URL similar to Google Calendar's `http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=ICS_URL` for Windows Live. The url links to the calendar web app and shows a popup whether the user wants to subscribe to the external ICS. I would like to open this URL from an app to guide the user towards subscription. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to subscribe to Hotmail/Outlook/Windows live calendar.

1)  Login to your Microsoft account.

2)  Go to the outlook menu bar and click the top left icon

3)  Click the calendar from the dropdown

4) Then click the import button that appears on the top.

*From this final screen you can both* **subscribe** *ICS files or* **import** *to a calendar.*

## To Subscribe

i) To [subscribe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrIU0.png) click on the menu item on the left-hand-side. 
ii) Lastly on the right-hand-side fill out both the [calendar URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywR3r.png) and a unique name for the calendar. Hit **subscribe** to add the calendar, *a color and charm can also be added.*

## To Import

a) Click on the menu item on the left-hand-side.
b) On the right hand-side choose from the drop down to add events to a new calendar or an existing calendar.  Hit **import** to add the calendar.